# How to add segment control on mapview using objective C?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, mkmapview

I am trying to create segment control on `mapview` using `storyboard`. Whenever I dragged and dropped on mapview storyboard isn't showing on output.

**FYI:** I have tried to add `UIView` on map view then segment on view also not adding.

Comment: Please try to make your post readable. I tried but I have no idea what are you trying to say with your sentences, eg "*then segment on view also not adding*" - makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Create `SegmentControl` using code and add it to your view.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
UISegmentedControl * cntrl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]   initWithItems:@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle"],@"2"]];
cntrl.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 200, 50);
[self.view addSubview:cntrl];
}
```

Set the frame as per your requirement.

I dragged and dropped segment control on top of the map view. Its showing fine. Find screenshot attached.

Comment: Btw I am trying storyboard.@Bharath Vankireddy

Answer (score 0):

1.I think you must add it to appdel.window, or use bringsubviewtofront function to bring the segment controller in front.

N.B:- appDel is the object of AppDelegate class.